# Equation for Neural Network from R output

Tags: r, neural-network

Hi I am a newbie in Depp learning fields.
I ran a neural network model (regression) with 2 hidden layers in R (neuralnet Package). then I used the the compute function to get the predicted probabilities.Now I want to regenerate predicted output using the  equation used in the neural net. for example, following are weights received from the model object

```
Intercept.to.1layhid1           4.55725020215

Var1.to.1layhid1               -13.61221477737

VAr2.to.1layhid1               0.30686384857

var1.to.1layhid2               0.23527690062

var2.to.1layhid2               0..67345678

1layhid.1.to.target            1.95414397785

1layhid.2.to.target            3.68009136857
```

Can any one help me derive a equation with the above weights so that I can replicate the output

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the output for new data, you can always use predict function using the fitted model, which is the returned object from *neuralnet* function.

For instance, if your model is the following:

```
neuralFit = neuralnet(trainData)
```

Then you reproduce the output with the following:

```
predict(neuralFit,newdata)
```

Otherwise, you'll need to compute the result manually. But you need to understand your network architecture first.